# Aggregate data by based on 3 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

suppose we have a data set like this:

Year State SomeValue

```
2000 NY   1000
2000 NY   1200
2000 NY   1100
2001 NY   2000
2001 NY   2200
...
```

How can I aggregate all 3 columns to have a data set look like:

```
year state somevalue
2000 NY 3300
2001 NY 4200


aggregate(data$year, list(data$state, data$somevalue), data, sum)
```

is this the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm there are numerous ways to aggregate data in R. Using `aggregate()`, you could e.g. do

```
aggregate(SomeValue ~ Year+State, data=data, FUN=sum)
```

or

```
with(data, aggregate(x = SomeValue, by = list(Year=Year, State=State), FUN = sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably spend some time with the basics of R syntax before doing such things -- your attempt hints at a fundamental misunderstanding of some things in R, but the following might do the trick for you:

```
x <- aggregate(somevalue ~ year + state, data=data, FUN=sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf( "select year , state , sum( somevalue ) as sum_somevalue from data group by year , state" )
```

Answer (score 0):

if `dat` is the dataset

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
group_by(year, state) %>%
summarise(somevalue=sum(somevalue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested solution was very close.  Here is a slightly modified version that does not return a warning:

```
data <- read.table(text='
year state somevalue
2000 NY   1000
2000 NY   1200
2000 NY   1100
2001 NY   2000
2001 NY   2200
', header=TRUE)

aggregate(data$somevalue, list(data$state, data$year), sum)
```

Although, @lukeA's solutions and @Livius's solution are better in base `R` because they return the desired column names in the requested order.

This returns two of the three requested column names:

```
aggregate(data$somevalue, list(state=data$state, year=data$year), sum)
```

My second solution differs from LukeA's second solution only in that I did not use the `with` function and did not label the `aggregate` options.  His answer is better.